# German: hin and her prefixes

Tags: german, prefixes

I have found the words with prefixes her and hin and I am little bit confused. I understand, hopefully correctly that hin means from me -> to somewhere else direction and her from somewhere -> to me directly or so.

But what I do not understand the difference between two words, **unterfallen** and **herunterfallen** or **herausfinden** and **ausfinden**. To me, it looks like they should mean absolutely the same thing and her prefix is arbitrarily added? Am I correct or is there any rule of thumb on how to know if such a prefix should be added or not?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This would be a better fit for [german.se].